# non-static method 'inflate(byte[],int,int)' cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java, android

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view= Inflater.inflate(R.layout.reg_book,container,false);
    return view;
    }
```

Context: I'm very beginner to android, I'm facing an error of " non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context ". Error shown at ' .inflate '.

Comment: `Inflater.inflate` should be `inflater.inflate` with lower case I

Comment: Thanks, it's come to my mind just after posting this question, 
The problem i'm facing now is how to get different fragments call from a single activity, that activity have buttons for every fragment. i just want when i click any button that particular fragment called, and fragment should called and it's layout. here some code for activity to fragment fragment to layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this line

```
view= Inflater.inflate(R.layout.reg_book,container,false);
```

to

```
view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.reg_book,container,false);
```

Answer (score 0):

As part of the `onCreateView`'s argument list, you receive `LayoutInflater inflater`.

Call the `.inflate(R.layout.reg_book,container,false)` on the above `inflater` variable.